# Get all combinations of six players

Tags: ruby

I have an array of six players. This means I have fifteen unique games:

```
players = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
games = players.combination(2).to_a
# => [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [1, 6], [2, 3], [2, 4], [2, 5], 
#    [2, 6], [3, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6], [4, 5], [4, 6], [5, 6]]
```

I want to arrange these games randomly into 5 rounds of 3. Each player should play 1 game each round, and no pair should repeat from any previous round.

In each round, I have tried picking `player1` and `player2` randomly, using `while` loop coupled with `each`, but I always end up in infinite loop. Any suggestions?

So here is the code (sorry for not putting it in eariler). Problem is that sometimes it does work and gives me the result that I want but sometimes it just breaks down and it's caught in the loop.

```
def pick_pair(players)
    player1 = players[rand(players.length)]
    players.delete(player1)
    player2 = players[rand(players.length)]
    players.delete(player2)
    pair = [player1, player2]
    return pair.sort!
end

def check_round(all_rounds, current_round)
    repeat = false
    if all_rounds == []
        repeat = false
    else
        repeat = catch :repeat do
            k = 0
            all_rounds.each do |round|
                a_r_l = all_rounds.length
                round.each do |pair|
                    r_l = round.length
                    k += 1
                    z = 0
                    current_round.each do |new_pair|
                        #p "Comparing: #{pair} to #{new_pair}"
                        z += 1
                        if pair == new_pair
                            repeat = true
                            throw :repeat, repeat
                        elsif (k == a_r_l*r_l  and z == current_round.length and pair != new_pair)
                            repeat = false
                            throw :repeat, repeat
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
        end
     end
     return repeat
 end

players = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
all_rounds = []

for i in 1..(players.length-1)
    #p "Round: #{i}"
    players_d = players.dup
    current_round = catch :round do 
        check = true
        while check
            current_round = []
            for j in 1..(players.length/2)
                #p "Game: #{j}"
                pair = pick_pair(players_d)
                current_round << pair
            end
            p "Previous rounds: #{all_rounds}"
            p "Current round: #{current_round}"
            repeat = check_round(all_rounds, current_round)
            if repeat == false
                throw :round, current_round
            else
                players_d = players.dup
            end
        end
    end
   all_rounds << current_round
 end
```

Hey,

thanks for the help. I rewrote the code and it seems to works. It's also much simpler:

```
players = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
possible_games = players.combination(2).to_a
all_games = []

for i in 1..(players.length - 1)
    round = catch :round do
            check = true
            while check
                round = []
                for i in 1..(players.length/2)
                    pair = possible_games[rand(possible_games.length)]
                    round << pair
                end
                if round.flatten.uniq == round.flatten
                    round.each do |game|
                        possible_games.delete(game)
                    end
                    throw :round, round
                else
                end
            end
        end
    all_games << round.sort!
end
p all_games
```

Comment: It's pretty hard to answer this without knowing the inputs and outputs of these two functions, but I would recommend starting with a shuffled version of your games and look at http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html (especially include?, select, and flatten).

Comment: Let's talk about what you mean by 'random'. To make a random 'assignment' of players (that meets the rules) I would think you would need to identify all feasible assignments, then select one of those at random. By 'assignment', I mean an outcome which specifies the rounds in which each player plays each of the other players Obviously, it would be easier if you find a single (feasible) assignment, then randomly assign the players to the six assignment positions. Would that be OK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you are trying for random combinations and retrying until the scheme is valid. It will succeed now and then, but it will get in a deadlock sometimes:

```
Round 1  2  3  4  5
      12 14 16 13 
      34 36 32 5??
      56 52 54
```

In round 4, player 5 must play player 1 or 3, but that is not going to happen because 3 is already playing 1. Your script keeps retrying until the end of times.

Such a tournament is called a round-robin tournament; wikipedia has [an algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament#Scheduling_algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

Although, strictly speaking, the best (most efficient) solution here would be to use a "round-robin" algorithm as suggested by steenslang.

I would suggest a simpler approach which works great and is quite straight forward.

Basically, the program tries to make each round have each player playing once per round. It loops over a shuffled array of combinations and tries pairing them up. If the combination is not possible, it reshuffles the array and tries again.

It's simple and it works great.

Plus, you can change the number of players if you need to too and it just works.

Hope this helps:

```
players = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
initial_games = players.combination(2).to_a.shuffle
players_sum = players.inject{|sum,x| sum + x }
all_rounds = []

games = initial_games
until games.empty?
  current_round = []
  games.each do |game| 
    if (current_round.flatten & game).empty?
      current_round << game
    end
  end
  current_round_sum = current_round.flatten.inject{|sum,x| sum + x } 
  if current_round_sum == players_sum
    all_rounds << current_round
    games = games - current_round
  else
    all_rounds = []
    games = initial_games.shuffle
  end
end

puts all_rounds.inspect  # this outputs 5 rounds of 3 games
```